# Access GlobalKTable via InteractiveQueryService in multiple bindings

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, kafka-streams-binder

I would like to create a service to access some reference data coming from Kafka in my kafka-streams applications using kafka-streams-binder via `GlobalKTable` and the `InteractiveQueryService`. That is quite easy when I add that `GlobalKTable` as an input in my binding:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun aggregatePositions(interactiveQueryService: InteractiveQueryService): Function<KStream<String, Event>, Function<GlobalKTable<String, ReferenceData>, KStream<String, String>>> {
    return Function { eventStream ->
        Function { referenceDataTable ->
            eventStream
                .mapValues { event ->
                    val store = interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore(
                        referenceDataTable.queryableStoreName(),
                        QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore<String, ReferenceData>()
                    )
                    "id: ${event.id} - type: ${store.get(event.typeId).typeName}"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I have various kafka-streams applications which need to resolve that reference data I wanted to extract that somehow to a spring-boot-starter and not actually add that `GlobalKTable` as parameter to the binding but make it available in all the bindings somehow.

Is there a good place where to hook into the creation of the topology to add that GlobalKTable to each binding or would it be better to create a separate topology for that and make the statestore available for the binding functions?